# System Recovery will not run from boot CD

Tags: windows-7, boot, system-repair-disc

A friend dropped off a Dell Studio 1555 for me to try and fix. Its running windows 7. I have found and removed lots of malware and now trying to fix the incredibly slow startup time.

1. I first was presented with the screen asking to "Repair Startup (Recommended)" or "Start Windows" I chose repair and it loaded the pointer and desktop background and nothing else. Even after waiting 6 hours it never started the system repair software.
2. I can not boot into Safe Mode either, it just loads a bunch of files and then reboots again taking me to the screen stated in 1.
3. I downloaded the System Repair Disk and burned ISO file from here: http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/create-a-windows-7-system-repair-disc/ 
   I then attempted to boot from disk and go the normal actions
   "Press any key to boot from CD/DVD"
   "Promted to select language and keyboard language"
   At this point thats as far as it gets. Pointer loaded and desktop background image loads and nothing els happens after this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand.  If you have removed malware then it worked at some point.  If it worked then you should be able to use the System Restore to rollback the system, in order to get it to the point of working again.  Clearly you have removed something that you shouldn't have or didn't fully remove that soemthing I should say.

Comment: Not really sure what your specific question is.  Start troubleshooting hardware.  Test the RAM, test the hard drives, etc.

Comment: I am unable to boot to last know working configuration. I was testing disabling some startup items with no luck in speeding up the boot process. I set it all back to normal and shut down for the day. Upon returning the next day I began having this problem or it not starting up or being able to run system repair from a boot disk.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this assuming that the computer still boots into windows but ONLY into normal mode but does so slowly.

The computer at this point is not loading Safe Mode, or from bootable media, so it is likely there is still an infection present in the Master Boot Record.

First Run the latest version of TDSSkiller.exe to remove common rootkits. TDSSkiller is easy to use, effective against many common infections with symptoms such as you describe and not much can go wrong when you run the program.
https://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/disinfection/5350

Then run MBRcheck to check the validity of the master boot record.
http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/mbrcheck.html
If it detects invalid MBR it will allow you to reset it.

If these do help I advise you look at going to a malware removal help forum, SuperUser is not really ideal for this type of support. Give it a try though, and I Hope it helps.

Comment: In the past couple of hours I was able to obtain the original install disk with no luck booting from that disk either. By the way it will not boot into windows normally. I ran another hardware diagnostic with returned an hard drive error. When googling the error code all evidence point to failed/failing hard drive or back sectors. So Im assuming at this point the HD is gone.